# How to compile and install DNScrypt

Tags: software-installation

Apparently there are no .deb packages available for installing DNScrypt. So I am forced to compile and install.

I downloaded the package from here http://download.dnscrypt.org/dnscrypt-proxy/

followed the instructions from here http://dnscrypt.org/

after extracting, I cd into directory, `./configure` and then when I type `make` I get:

```
No targets specified and no make file found.
```

What is going on? How do I get dnscrypt installed?

Answer (score 8):

I bet you forgot a the libsodium library:

```
checking for library containing sodium_init... no
configure: error: libsodium not found
```

Quoting installation guide:

> Install libsodium. There might be a pre-built binary package for your operating system already.

Unfortunally, there are not libsodium packages for Ubuntu. So, you should download, build and install `libsodium` as follows:

1. Download the newer tar archive from https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/ (you can also get the git repository from https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium).  If you downloaded the tar.gz file, **you should verify the hashsum**:

   ```
   $ dig +dnssec +short txt libsodium-0.4.2.tar.gz.download.libsodium.org
   "1a7901cdd127471724e854a8eb478247dc0ca67be549345c75fc6f2d4e05ed39"
   $ shasum -a 256 libsodium-0.4.2.tar.gz
   1a7901cdd127471724e854a8eb478247dc0ca67be549345c75fc6f2d4e05ed39  libsodium-0.4.2.tar.gz
   ```

   As we can see, both are **identical**. You can also use the `.sig` file.
2. Follow the ritual:

   ```
   tar xzf libsodium-0.4.2.tar.gz
   cd libsodium-0.4.2/
   ./configure
   make && make check && sudo make install
   ```

   You should consider debianize the package so it's more easy for you to uninstall/update later. There are plenty guides about this.
3. Once you have installed you have to reload/rebuild the GNU linkers. A simple `sudo ldconfig` is enough.
4. Now run `./configure` and it should generate the makefile. (I'm assuming you have at least `build-essentials` package installed).

   ```
   checking for library containing sodium_init... -lsodium
   .....
   checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
   configure: creating ./config.status
   config.status: creating Makefile
   config.status: creating config.h
   config.status: executing depfiles commands
   config.status: executing libtool commands
   ```

   Those are the ending lines of the `./configure`.

Remember to keep a keen eye on the updates and bugs for both packages, since **there might be vulnerabilities** that shall be fixed with hassle.

Comment: Actually, the correct answer is Githlar's.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae [not necesarily](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy#installation).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the problem is that the instruction on dnscrypt.org are actually wrong. Prior to doing ./configure you have to do ./autogen.sh.

1. `./autogen.sh`
2. `./configure.sh` (with libsodium installed as above. Hint: `sudo apt-get install checkinstall`)
3. `make`
4. `sudo checkinstall`

Comment: just to note - this one is important addition

Answer (score 0):

For anyone receiving a similar error in the future, it could be the case that you do not have `libsodium-dev` installed. Installing it will allow `dnscrypt` to compile successfully. Of course, the easier route is to use the `dnscrypt-autoinstall` script.